# How to simplify the inequality $5c * 3^{n-2} + 3 \le c3^n$

Tags: inequality

I'm stuck on trying to simplify the inequality:

$5c * 3^{n-2} + 3 \le c3^n$

I'm looking for an expression such as $c \ge x$ without the n
to show when this inequality holds true

Edit:

This inequality arises in the context of solving a recurrence relation with the substitution method.

I just need to show this inequality holds for $n \ge 2$

Logically I can see that if c = 1, $5*3^{n-2} +3 \le 3^n$ holds for $n \ge 2$ but not sure how to prove it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Just note $$5c*3^{n-2}+3\le c3^n$$ $$\iff c(3^{n-1}-5\cdot3^{n-3})\ge 1$$ $$\iff 4\cdot3^{n-3}c\ge 1,$$ $$c\ge\frac{1}{4\cdot3^{n-3}}$$
If we need this inequality holds for all positive integer $n$ then we have $c\ge\frac{9}{4}$.

Comment: how'd u get $c\ge\frac{9}{4}$

Comment: @LÜHECCHEgon : The sequence $\left\{\frac1{4\cdot3^{n-3}}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is decreasing, then in order to satisfy $c\geq\frac1{4\cdot3^{n-3}}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ it is enough $c\geq\frac1{4\cdot3^{1-3}}=\frac{1}{4\cdot 3^{-2}}=\frac94$.

Comment: why substitute n=1

Answer (score 0):

Put $x = 3^n$. You have
$$ \frac{5x}{9}  + 3 \le cx.$$
Can you go the rest of the way?

Comment: What I really need is an inequality with c that is not in terms of n, is that possible?